# Nullability of stored proc result column datatypes

Tags: sql-server

When one executes a stored proc against MS SQL Server, the recordset comes with some type info. Clients are capable of retrieving that type info, e. g. like this (C#/.NET):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProc", conn);
SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ada.Fill(ds);
string ColName = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;
Type ColType = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].DataType;
```

What about nullability of those columns? While it's not knowable in the general case, sometimes it is - for example, when a recordset column comes straight from a table field. If SQL Server is smart enough, it can determine column nullability at least for those cases. **Does SQL Server report nullability to the clients in whatever metadata it provides along with the recordset?**

Specifically in the .NET client, there is `AllowDBNull` in retrieved column properties, but in the scenario above it's unreliable - it comes across as `true` both for columns that came from nullable fields, and for columns that came from *nonnullable* fields. **Is this a limitation of the .NET client, or a shortcoming of the underlying protocol?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a limitation of `SqlDataAdapter`.**

The TDS protocol does return this information, as you can [see in the specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/58880b9f-381c-43b2-bf8b-0727a98c4f4c).

In turn, `SqlDataReader` will return this information via `GetSchemaTable`. But it does not make its way to a table filled using a `DbDataAdapter`.

You can see this with the following code

```cs
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var comm = new SqlCommand("select 1", conn))
    using(var reader=comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.GetSchemaTable().Dump();
    }

    using(var comm = new SqlCommand("select case when getdate() = 1 then 1 end", conn))
    using(var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.GetSchemaTable().Dump();
    }
}
```

You will see that the first has `AllowDBNull` as `false` and the second as `true`.

---

I would advise you in any case to avoid `SqlDataAdapter`, as it is only actually useful in data-binding UI scenarios. In back-end code, just use a `SqlDataReader`, or even better: use an ORM such as Dapper or Entity Framework, which will sort out all of this kind of thing for you.